# Show 3 scrollable ListViews of equal height in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to show three different vertical sections in my Android layout on one screen, each taking up one third of the screen, one on the top, one in the middle, and one on the bottom. Each section has a `TextView` and a `ListView`, and the `ListViews` can scroll so that you can see all items, but the overall page does not move. I have tried putting each `TextView` and `ListView` in a `LinearLayout` and setting the height of each `LinearLayout` to one third the total height of the screen, but the first `ListView` just shows all the items in it, taking up most of the screen, and the other sections are pushed down. I also tried using layout_weights, but for some reason it did not work. (EDIT: Setting `layout_weight="1"` ended up working, I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time) How can I make this work, or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ListView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#FF0000"/>

  <ListView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#00FF00">

  <ListView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#0000FF">

</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you three equally wide columns: to make it rows, change the orientation to vertical and swap the values of `layout_height` and `layout_width` for each listview. If you need to add the `TextView`s, you'll have to make each listview in this code either a `RelativeLayout` `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`, using same width/height/weight and arranging the `ListView` and `TextView` inside to taste. To do this most efficiently, use a `Framelayout` and use a margin on the listview to offset it from the `TextView`. You can place the `TextView` relative to the `ListView` inside the `FrameLayout` by using the `layout_gravity` in the `TextView`.

Ie (swapping the first "column"):

```
<FrameLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dp"    
  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent"   
  android:background="#FF0000">

  <TextView android:text="Column!" android:background="#3Eff0000"
    android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <ListView android:layout_marginTop="48dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"      
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="#8Aff0000"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked; originally I had tried using weights but for some reason it did not work, this method did work though!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff89ff91">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="#1"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff8177">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="#2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffe85d">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="#3"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```